# Node and Neo4J in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, neo4j

I'm trying to run neo4J in causal cluster mode. All is meant to be run in docker with a config inside `docker-compose.yml`. All instances of the cluster are running, however when I'm trying to connect to neo4J thru Node.js (which of course is also run by the same `docker-compose.yml`) I'm getting: `Neo4j :: executeQuery :: Error Neo4jError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND neo4j`. How can I make it work, ie. connect from node to neo4J in causal cluster mode inside docker container. Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  lan:

services:

  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./
    links:
      - core1
      - core2
      - core3
      - read1
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_NEO4J_HOST=bolt://neo4j

  core1:
    image: neo4j:3.5.11-enterprise
    networks:
      - lan
    ports:
      - 7474:7474
      - 6477:6477
      - 7687:7687
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core1/conf:/conf
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core1/data:/data
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core1/logs:/logs
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core1/plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_NEO4J_HOST=bolt://neo4j
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/changeme
      - NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__formation=3
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__runtime=3
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_initial__discovery__members=core1:5000,core2:5000,core3:5000
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7474
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6477
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7687

  core2:
    image: neo4j:3.5.11-enterprise
    networks:
      - lan
    ports:
      - 7475:7475
      - 6478:6478
      - 7688:7688
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core2/conf:/conf
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core2/data:/data
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core2/logs:/logs
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core1/plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_NEO4J_HOST=bolt://neo4j
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/changeme
      - NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__formation=3
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__runtime=3
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_initial__discovery__members=core1:5000,core2:5000,core3:5000
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7475
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6478
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7688

  core3:
    image: neo4j:3.5.11-enterprise
    networks:
      - lan
    ports:
      - 7476:7476
      - 6479:6479
      - 7689:7689
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core3/conf:/conf
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core3/data:/data
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core3/logs:/logs
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core1/plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_NEO4J_HOST=bolt://neo4j
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/changeme
      - NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__formation=3
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_minimum__core__cluster__size__at__runtime=3
      - NEO4J_causal__clustering_initial__discovery__members=core1:5000,core2:5000,core3:5000
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7476
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6479
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7689

  read1:
    image: neo4j:3.5.11-enterprise
    networks:
      - lan
    ports:
      - 7477:7477
      - 6480:6480
      - 7690:7690
    volumes:
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-read1/conf:/conf
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-read1/data:/data
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-read1/logs:/logs
      - $HOME/neo4j/neo4j-core1/plugins:/plugins
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_NEO4J_HOST=bolt://neo4j
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/changeme
      - NEO4J_dbms_mode=READ_REPLICA
      - NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes
      - NEO4J_causalClustering_initialDiscoveryMembers=core1:5000,core2:5000,core3:5000
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_http_listen__address=:7477
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_https_listen__address=:6480
      - NEO4J_dbms_connector_bolt_listen__address=:7690
```

And my DockerFile.dev:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app'
RUN apk update && apk add yarn python g++ make && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The application should be attached to same network.

```
app:
  networks:
    - lan
```

2) Assuming the network already exists with name "lan" or create a new network

```
  networks:
    lan:
      driver: bridge
```

3) **deprecated** "links" in docker-

```
  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./
    links:
      - core1
      - core2
      - core3
      - read1
```

instead of this use - [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dependson) if required to maintain loading sequence

=======================

**Edit** Please read comments for the followup questions

Comment: Thank you for your answer but for some reason the error still occurs. I'm not sure what is the correct URI to connect to neo4j db inside the docker (I keep it in env,  - REACT_APP_NEO4J_HOST=bolt://neo4j, but I guess it is wrong

Comment: Yes, you must mention `hostname: neo4j` to resolve DNS `neo4j`.

Comment: When connecting with cluster - `bolt+routing://<host>:<port>` should be used.

Comment: So bolt+routing is for me, but what exactly should this uri looks like when fired on local machine? Also what port should I use because every instance is on separate port? To which should I connect?

Comment: It's a nice follow up question. You should use host:port combination of core servers not read replicas. How to identify cor/master /leader `NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE`

Comment: Try connecting using browser to cluster master server.

Comment: So as I understand I connect to any core server (NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE) f.ex. the first one, it will be aware of other servers? I'm missing those steps in official neo4j docs.

Comment: Yes, the understanding is correct. There are multiple ways to make your cluster available as there are chances something might go wrong with initial/seed instance. FYR: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/setup-new-cluster/